# 1120: Access of undefined property stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cc

I'm trying to make a class however I get these errors:

> ... \SubtitleLoader.as, Line 14, Column 8 1120: Access of undefined
>   property stage. ... \SubtitleLoader.as, Line 20, Column 10    1061: Call
>   to a possibly undefined method addEventListener through a reference
>   with static type SubtitleLoader.

Here's my code:

```
package
{
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;

    public class SubtitleLoader
    {
        private var str:String;

        public function init():void
        {
            if (stage)
            {
                LoadText();
            }
            else
            {
                this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
            }
        }

        private function onAddedToStage(event:Event):void
        {
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);

            LoadText();
        }

        private function LoadText():void
        {
            var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("aman.srt");
            var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            urlLoader.load(url);
            urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
        }

        private function onComplete(event:Event):void
        {
            trace(event.data);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add events because your class doesn't extend EventDispatcher. Your class can't be added to the stage because it doesn't extend any display classes. You probably want to extend `flash.display.Sprite` (which also extends EventDispatcher):

```
package
{
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.display.Sprite; //import sprite
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;

    public class SubtitleLoader extends Sprite //extend sprite, inheriting EventDispatcher as well
    {
```

Also, it is bad coding style to give your function names UpperCamelCase (LoadText). UpperCamelCase is reserved for class names.

Comment: Holy cow I actually answered a question and it got accepted and everything. Now I almost have enough internet points to leave comments!

No problem, glad to help.